# How can I select all roofs in blender and change material

Tags: blender-osm

This is my building. I don't want to select each for each roof. 
How can I select all roofs and then change material?

Thank you for answer.

[image]

Comment: i have tried test with cube. I have 3 the same cube. If cube has different dimension (roof) how blender know what need to selected? In your case not works or I forgot something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (*Select Similar*) > *Normal*, it will select all the faces that point in the same direction. You can extend its threshold in the *Operator* box. Then in the *Properties* panel > *Material*, choose the material and press *Assign*.

Comment: your answer works, only problem was need to add threshold 0.10

Comment: so some faces were probably a little bit tilted?

Comment: @progy85 Hello and welcome. Don't just comment that the answer worked, upvote the post instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted